# Obtaining the type, class, and the text from HTML tag

Tags: r, regex

I have a big data containing HTML tag, I need to the the result like this. But I don't know how to obtain this.

```
                                                            text
1 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
2 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
3 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
```

My desired output like this:

```
type             class                   Text
type="button" class="btn btn-default" Default 
type="button" class="btn btn-primary" Primary
type="button" class="btn btn-success" Success
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `extract` to capture substring based on the pattern in the 'text' column to split the column into multiple columns

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, text, into = c("type", "class", "text"),
         ".*(type=[^ ]+)\\s+([^>]+)>(\\w+).*")
#          type                   class    text
#1 type="button" class="btn btn-default" Default
#2 type="button" class="btn btn-primary" Primary
#3 type="button" class="btn btn-success" Success
```

**Explanation**

`.*` - characters

`(type = [^ ]+)` - capture substring from 'type = ' and one or more characters  that are not a space `[^ ]+`

`\\s+` - one or more space

`([^>]+)` - second capture group that captures one or more characters not a `>`

`>` - the character `>`

`(\\w+)` - third capture group to capture the word

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(text = c("<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\">Default</button>", 
"<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Primary</button>", 
"<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success\">Success</button>"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: Can you explain this to me: ([^>]+). It is new to me.

Comment: @user14090295 thanks.  added the explanation. Hope it works

Comment: Yes. It works. But the second group I am not clear enough actually.

Comment: @user14090295 It is based on the pattern your showed.  i.e. in the second group, there are no characters that are `>`.  So it is used to identify and capture that group

Answer (score 1):

This is usually frown upon to parse xml with regex, but if you need to do it, *{unglue}* proposes an intuitive solution (using @akrun's data) :

```r
library(unglue)

unglue_unnest(df1, text, "<button {type} {class}>{Text}</button>")
#>            type                   class    Text
#> 1 type="button" class="btn btn-default" Default
#> 2 type="button" class="btn btn-primary" Primary
#> 3 type="button" class="btn btn-success" Success
```